# Facebox with other jquery in it

Tags: jquery, facebox

So I have facebox setup and it works. when I load an external page with a tab based navigation (JQuery too) the modal works but the nav doesnt. If it isnt clear I actually want the tabs to be inside the lightbox. And I also have php/mysql running inside the lightbox if that can change anything. Thanks for any help.

This is the original modal call

```
<link href="facebox/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="facebox/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
});
```

This is the script in the page that the modal box calls up

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#tabs').tabs();
        });
</script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Informations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Factures en attente</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Marché en cours</a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="tabs-1"> one</div>
<div id="tabs-2"> two</div>
<div id="tabs-3">three</div>
```

Comment: You have php and mysql running inside the lightbox. Wow!. No just kidding.

Comment: I am unfortunately and it works dog gonnit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not enough details here for me.. Where is the modal markup/call? Where are your containers that the tabs reference?

See the source for the example here:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

If you aren't using containers, the tabs have nothing to interact with and may appear to not work.

Edit:

According to the official doc, this should work, after loading the jquery:

```
<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Tab 1 content</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Tab 2 content</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Tab 3 content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Have you tried the exact example to see if it works? If that doesn't work, Facebox may be interfering somehow. Try reducing it to the simplest form without a lot going on and see if it works, then start slowly adding things.

Comment: That doesnt seem to work either thanks for the help, I guess Ill just have to find a workaround in my UI that doesnt ask for ajax in the modal

Comment: I just did what Kevin suggest. See my answer. Simplest possible setup with exactly the code you posted in your question

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce. Made a simple demo here http://jsbin.com/iposi3/2 which loads http://jsbin.com/uwoxe/2. Note it is vital that the loaded remote page isn't a full-blown-html page, so no `html`, `head`, `body` tags or the like else it will fail completly. Only a "html-fragment" as the one you have shown.

To view the code use http://jsbin.com/iposi3/2/edit and http://jsbin.com/uwoxe/2/edit

Works just fine in my Opera. Although of course the facebox is too small to show the tabs nicely with default settings.

---

To your problem I recall (check [my post on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821047/very-interesting-jquery-load-behavior-a-bug-or-solution/1821182#1821182)) that jQuery sometimes strips the `script` tags from remote loaded content. But that seems to apply only when `$.load` is used which FaceBox doesn't (it uses `$.get` for remote content).

Which browser do you experience problems in? If it is IE it could be that IE throws "Permission Denied" errors when jQuery tries to inject the script tags from the remote content. Did you check your browsers error console?

Comment: i tried in firefox and oracle the links you posted they dont work in either.

Comment: ? What browser version. Works just fine for me in Opera 10.10 and FF 3.6. Firefox Screenshot: http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/2871/firefoxop.jpg; Opera Screenshot: http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/5750/operaho.jpg