# jQuery incompatibility with Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I'm using a simple piece of code

`$("container").load(url, function(){ callback();})`

to replace the content of a div container using jQuery's AJAX functionality. That appears to work well with Internet Explorer, however after trying to view it through Firefox I am getting some unexpected behaviour.

The page is fetched and placed correctly inside the div only for a moment; then the whole page appears to refresh automatically and seems to redirect itself to a page prefixed with

```
wyciwyg://1/http://
```

Needless to say that it just hangs there with a blank page and nothing happens unless I click on Firefox's stop button. Are there differences between IE/Firefox that could be causing such a behaviour in jQuery? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what *you* see is what *I* get

Comment: What's the URL you are loading?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer cballou. I looked up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYCIWYG. Ok, but how can I avoid this?

Comment: Ben, it's a local URL pointing to another page. Due to the way it is generated it contains the entire URL (http://localhost:8080/..etc) - don't know if that could cause a problem.

Comment: What's the url? console.log or alert it. What's your callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably `<script>` tags in the document returned at the targeted `url`.

Loading content into the page that contains `<script>` tags has browser specific quirks that jQuery cannot hide (well... it tries, but in the process makes the quirks even more quirky and strange). You should avoid fetching a page that contains `<script>` for use as HTML as with `load()`. Which means generally don't `load` arbitrary pages containing any old HTML constructs, but only addresses that are intended for use with jQuery content loading.

Whilst it's difficult to say why a script in the target page might end up replacing the page with a [wyciwyg URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYCIWYG) without some code to play with, it has happened in the past with [calls to `document.write`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=244678), which is a behaviour that will definitely cause breakage in general as you can't write to `document` from an already-parsed document like the one you'll be loading into. It could also be an interaction with an add-on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bobince, the target page does indeed contain <script> tags. In such a case I must assume that when jQuery evals the newly fetched js a refresh is forced causing the momentarily correct page to be replaced by a blank one. Now where to start looking..

Comment: Looking for `document.write` would certainly be my first tack. But in general you don't want to be loading pages with `<script>` in. That way lies madness.

Comment: I disagree with bobince. There is nothing wrong with loading a page containing `<script>` tags if you take care to understand what is going on, and it's often unavoidable.

Comment: See eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661224/stop-ie-from-loading-dynamically-included-script-twice for a hint of the difficulties involved.

Answer (score 2):

If `document.write` is your problem, try [writeCapture.js](http://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture) (full disclosure: I'm the author). It has a [jQuery plugin](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/iamnoah/writeCapture/jquery.writeCapture-0.3.0-min.js) so include it and change your code to:

```
$("container").writeCapture().load(url, function(){ callback();});
```

and see if that doesn't fix the problem.