# jQuery AJAX functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, load

I am using jQuery's load() function when getting a page to a div like that:

content.php page is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(".content").load("asd.php");
</script>
```

and asd.php is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Hello World");
</script>
```

When load ajax finished alert() message appears 3 times. Actually it must appears only 1 time. So load() function get page 3 times.

How can I get the page a time?

Comment: do you have only one ".content" item? everything is looking good. check firebug NET reposes as advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably facing the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661224/stop-ie-from-loading-dynamically-included-script-twice).

Loading content which includes `<script>` elements into the page is massively unreliable. jQuery tries to paper over the issues but it doesn't quite succeed.

Best: Don't do it. Keep all your static JavaScript code separate from content loaded with `load()`, and use the post-loading callback to run any JavaScript code you need to bind to the new page content.

Comment: You are saying that: don't use ajax. Or I understand wronglyi

Comment: You can use AJAX, but don't write anything including `<script>` to an element's `innerHTML` (as jQuery's `html()` or `load()` would). Keep scripts out of the content you are using AJAX to inject into the page.

Comment: hmm, sound good. But according to my project, I must load some pages using AJAX with injecting to the content.

Comment: You can load some pages using AJAX to inject their content, but don't include `<script>` in that content. It doesn't really make sense to, anyway: scripts are supposed to be run once per main page load, not on each sub-navigation. If the scripts include any logic that depends on not defining the same variable or function twice, or needs to run at document load time (ie. `document.write()`), there's no way it could work anyway.

Comment: How will I load without <script> using AJAX?

Comment: Take `<script>` blocks out of the `asd.php` that you are loading, and include any logic inside them in scripts loaded by `content.php`. Pass a completed-callback `function() { // do asd stuff }` to the `load()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure content loaded three times? Have you used firebug to watch what is actually transfered?

Comment: When I open firebug to watch it, it(alert() message) appears a time. But another times it appears 3 times.