# How to stop Knockout 3.2 library loading twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

I have the issue that binding expressions such as

```
<div data-bind="text: $data.Property"></div>
```

-where `Property` is an observable- causes the actual text of knockout's observable function to display instead of the value `Property` is supposed to represent. This was addressed here [In IE8, KnockoutJS 3.2 displaying actual observable function rather than the observable's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825396/in-ie8-knockoutjs-3-2-displaying-actual-observable-function-rather-than-the-obs).

The cause of that issue was that duplicate knockout library files were being loaded. The "UPDATE:" section and answer of the linked SO question includes some detail around that.

I now need to know how to keep the knockout library from being loaded twice. *Emphasis on **loaded** not just executed.* So far I haven't found anything that quite answered this.

RequireJS: is used by the site but, not by the pages under investigation.

SignalR: is used by the page. I'm a bit unfamiliar with SignalR so I can't say how likely it is that this is causing multiple loads.

Ajax: is used as well but it is used to receive JSON data.

There is only 1 explicit reference to the knockout library.

Looking at the network tab, the first file is loaded from the [speculative download](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/27/bugs-in-the-ie8-lookahead-downloader.aspx) feature of IE. The second file is from the main parser. The first file is completely downloaded, and then the second is completely downloaded.

What I haven't been able to figure out is a way to keep:

- The Lookahead Downloader from downloading the file the first time
- The main parser from downloading the file a second time
- The file from being executed a second time without changing the code in the library file.

One of the above solutions can be acceptable at this point. Can anyone offer insight, suggestions or know of a solution to this?

Comment: A screencap of the network tab could be useful, especially if the two requests are not identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this figured out. The issue was the order that the scripts were listed in the page. ASP.NET MVC 5 supports renderable named sections. In this case `scripts`:

Layout -

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Views/Partial Views -

```
@section scripts {
    // script includes ...
}
```

In my case a partial view did not include scripts in a `scripts` section causing them to be parsed/downloaded by the preparser and the main parser.

Adding all scripts to `scripts` sections in the proper order solved this problem. The order has been determined by the the scripts' dependencies.